# awk delete line from csv if char length of second column is less than 12

Tags: awk

I have a csv which looks like so:

```
42242,"France."
2343242,"Laboratoire de Virologie, AP-HP, Hôpital Necker-Enfants malades, Paris, France."
234234,"brazil"
23432423,"colombia"
234234,"Université de Paris, Institut Cochin, INSERM U1016, CNRS UMR8104, Paris, France."
234234,"Paris."
```

I would like to delete rows where the char length of the second column is <12.

I think awk can do this:

```
awk -F , '$2=length>12' file >filout
```

but this seems wrong.. :(

I want to delete the line to get:

```
2343242,"Laboratoire de Virologie, AP-HP, Hôpital Necker-Enfants malades, Paris, France."
234234,"Université de Paris, Institut Cochin, INSERM U1016, CNRS UMR8104, Paris, France."
```

Comment: Like all Unix tools, awk has man pages: `man awk | grep length` outputs `length([s])             Return  the  length  of  the  string  s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your second field is contained within double quotes, you must use the double quote, rather than the comma, as the separator to determine the length of the second field:

```
awk -F\" 'length($2)>=12' file
```

---

If you just print the length of the second field, you will see what I mean. First using the comma as separator:

```
awk -F, '{print length($2)}' file
9
25
8
10
20
8
```

Second, using the double quote as the separator:

```
awk -F\" '{print length($2)}' file
7
79
6
8
80
6
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F, 'length($2)>=12' input_file
2343242,"Laboratoire de Virologie, AP-HP, Hôpital Necker-Enfants malades, Paris, France."
234234,"Université de Paris, Institut Cochin, INSERM U1016, CNRS UMR8104, Paris, France."
```

Comment: ah I was close :D

Answer (score 0):

*adding* `gsub(/[\200-\277]/, "&")` *to properly measure # of* `UTF-8` *characters in byte mode, assuming* `well-formed UTF-8` *input. skip this part if you're using* `gawk` *in unicode mode*

```
echo '42242,"France."
2343242,"Laboratoire de Virologie, AP-HP, Hôpital Necker-Enfants malades, Paris, France."
234234,"brazil"
23432423,"colombia"
234234,"Université de Paris, Institut Cochin, INSERM U1016, CNRS UMR8104, Paris, France."
234234,"Paris."' |
```

> — to do it the `CSV` way without a proper parser (or an `awk`  that's even unicode aware) - it measures full row length, minus string index position of 1st comma, then minus 2 more for the quotation marks :

- ```
  mawk '(_+=++_)^_^_<(-_-- + length($--_) \
                           - index($_, FS) \
                           - gsub(/[\200-\277]/, "&"))' FS=','
  ```

> - to do it the double-quotes (`"..."`) way :

- ```
  gawk '((_+=++_)^_^_-_^_)<length($(--_+_--))' FS='"'
  ```

> 

```
 1  2343242,"Laboratoire de Virologie, AP-HP, Hôpital Necker-Enfants malades, Paris, France."
 2  234234,"Université de Paris, Institut Cochin, INSERM U1016, CNRS UMR8104, Paris, France."
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ruby` with `CSV.parse` on slightly modified data to show correct output on commas within quotes.

```
% ruby -r 'csv' -ne 'if CSV.parse($_).map {|i| 
    if i[1].length >= 12 then true end}[0] then puts $_ end' file
2343242,"Labor, atoire de Virologie, AP-HP, Hôpital Necker-Enfants malades, Paris, France."
23432423,Institut Cochin,"colombia"
234234,"Université de Paris, Institut Cochin, INSERM U1016, CNRS UMR8104, Paris, France."
```

##### Data

```
% cat file
42242,"France."
2343242,"Labor, atoire de Virologie, AP-HP, Hôpital Necker-Enfants malades, Paris, France."
234234,"brazil"
23432423,Institut Cochin,"colombia"
234234,"Université de Paris, Institut Cochin, INSERM U1016, CNRS UMR8104, Paris, France."
234234,"Paris."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
42242,"France."
2343242,"Laboratoire de Virologie, AP-HP, Hôpital Necker-Enfants malades, Paris, France."
234234,"brazil"
23432423,"colombia"
234234,"Université de Paris, Institut Cochin, INSERM U1016, CNRS UMR8104, Paris, France."
234234,"Paris."
```

does have `,` *inside* quoted values, therefore just setting field separator to `,` would not work, observe that e.g. 2nd columnd of 2nd row will be `"Laboratoire de Virologie`, to counter that you might use `FPAT` provided in [More CSV chapter of GNU AWK manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gawk/manual/html_node/More-CSV.html) as follows

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"([^\"]|\"\")+\")"}length($2)>12' file.csv
```

though keep in mind that `"` are included in quotes fields, so you might need to adjust value inside comparison.

Comment: hmm but why is it that `awk -F, 'length($2)>=12' input_file` works in that case?

Comment: @JohnJ both `"Laboratoire de Virologie` and `"Université de Paris` have more than 12 characters